# MS Bot Framework - pass data through markdown link

Tags: c#, botframework

Is it possible to pass data through a markdown link? So for example:

```
 var html = "[link1](test1)  [link2](test2)";

 var reply = message.CreateReply();
 reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name + html}!";

 client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Is there a way to pick up the click event that would let me know which link was clicked?

Comment: No. The click takes place on the client, and no data from that is passed back to the server. If you really want to know, use tracking links.

Comment: do you have a resource i can review on that? not really finding much on it.

Comment: For tracking links? [A lot of URL shortening services offer tracking and analytics.](https://blog.bufferapp.com/url-shorteners) How you track what each _user_ is doing, though, is more complex. You might have to use the URL shortener's API to create individual links for each user.

Comment: oh i see. i misunderstood. i thought you were referring to something that was going to allow me to intercept click events from the chat. hmm.

Comment: No. It's up to the client application - Facebook, Web, Skype, Cortana etc - to render the markdown. They all know how to show a link. But when the user clicks that link, they don't send that information back to the bot.

Comment: so if i create a FB bot and host it in azure, you're saying i can't get the click events even if i try to implement something like a global handler or something?

Comment: How would you implement a global handler? You can't get your code to run in the Messenger interface.

Answer (score 1):

In bot framework, if you are trying to collect data off of link click (or button of the `OpenUrl` type).  The recommended way is by using a 302 redirect.  This is because you generally do not have access to anything from the front end as stuartd is pointing out.  For example, if you have a facebook bot how would you capture what the user clicks since nothing is sent to the bot?  This is the problem you are running into.  You would essentially have to send an activity to the bot when the user clicks a link, but without access to the Facebook front end how do you send that on click?

If you would like to see an example of a 302 redirect in a bot, I have made [this example which has both Node and C# versions](https://github.com/JasonSowers/BF-302RedirectExample).  This project shows how to do this with a button using the `OpenUrl` action type but can be applied to a link as well.